# Outline a transparent image using imagick PHP

Tags: php, image, imagick, outline

I have an image with a transparent background that I'd like to outline with a 5px border. In photoshop, I can stroke it to achieve this.

I've tried using `borderImage` but it won't outline the penguin.

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage('tux.png');

$image->borderImage(new ImagickPixel('red'), 5, 5); // no outline
```

This is the image.

[image: tux original]

This is what I want to achieve.

[image: tux outlined]

Comment: The morphology stuff has an example here http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/morphology?morphologyType=14

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll start at the command line and may do the PHP later, or let you work that bit out...

**Step 1 - Extract transparency**

As you have seen, `-border` outlines the *whole* image, but you actually want to outline the *opaque* areas only so you need to work with the transparency, or alpha layer. Let's extract that first:

```
convert tux.png -alpha extract alpha.png
```

[image]

**Step 2 - Get edges of opaque area**

Now, you want the edges of that outlined, so I'll use `-morphology`:

```
convert alpha.png -morphology edge octagon -threshold 50% edge.png
```

[image]

I have heard that folks are having difficulty with morphological operations in PHP, so here is an alternative method for this step that doesn't use morphology. Basically, it duplicates the alpha layer, and then uses statistics to find the brightest pixel in each 3x3 box (which is only going to have an effect at the edges where there are some black and some white pixels in the 3x3 box) and then differences the result with the original to show the affected pixels. Easier to just do than describe!

```
convert alpha.png \( +clone -statistic maximum 3x3 -threshold 50% \) -compose difference -composite edge.png
```

[image]

Use a 5x5 box for a fatter line.

I see there is an `-edge 5` option which is way easier - we live and learn!

**Step 3 - Make edges red and rest transparent**

Now you want the white to be red and the black to be transparent:

```
convert edge.png -fill red -opaque white -transparent black rededge.png
```

[image]

**Step 4 - Composite red outline over original**

And finally, you want to composite that over your original:

```
convert tux.png rededge.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

**The whole hog**

Or, you can do it all in one go like this:

```
convert tux.png  \( +clone -alpha extract -morphology edge octagon -threshold 50% -fill red -opaque white -transparent black \) -composite result.png
```

You may prefer the more subtle effect of `-morphology edgeout` over `-morphology edge`.

**PHP Version**

My PHP skills are *"low"*, but I have started and am making some progress - will update later, but so far it looks like this:

```
   $image = new Imagick("tux.png");
   $alpha = clone $image;
   $alpha->separateImageChannel(Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
   $alpha->negateImage(true);
   $alpha->edgeImage(5);
   $alpha->opaquePaintImage("white","red",65000,FALSE);
   $alpha->transparentPaintImage("black",0.0,0,FALSE);
   $image->compositeImage($alpha,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,0,0);
   $image->writeImage("result.png");
```

That seems to pretty much work, but some aspects could probably be tidied up - specifically the `65000` magic number and maybe some unnecessary cloning and stuff -I'll leave that to you!

Comment: Great solution! I've been trying to replicate it in PHP to no avail. Could you convert it to PHP?

Comment: I have attempted some amateurish PHP - I'll leave you to enhance it to production quality :-)

Comment: Great stuff, Mark! I appreciate it. Feel free to update it if you need to.

Comment: Step 3 is not working - I get an empty output image :/

Comment: how thin can you make the outline?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzKRI.jpg)    function getCharacterOutline() {

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath("pen.png"));
$character = new \Imagick();
$character->newPseudoImage(
    $imagick->getImageWidth(),
    $imagick->getImageHeight(),
    "canvas:white"
);
$canvas = new \Imagick();
$canvas->newPseudoImage(
    $imagick->getImageWidth(),
    $imagick->getImageHeight(),
    "canvas:black"
);

$character->compositeimage(
    $imagick,
    \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY,
    0, 0
);
$canvas->compositeimage(
    $character,
    \Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,
    0, 0
);
$canvas->setFormat('png');

return $canvas;
```

}

```
$canvas = getCharacterOutline();
$kernel   =\ImagickKernel::fromBuiltIn(\Imagick::KERNEL_OCTAGON, "3");
$canvas->morphology(\Imagick::MORPHOLOGY_EDGE, 1, $kernel);
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
echo $canvas->getImageBlob();
 [result][1]
```

Comment: how thin can you make the outline?