# PHP ImageMagick: how to antialias a line

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am having problems with line having jagged edges (see white line):

[image]

If I reduce stroke (from 10 to 4), then it's OK, but the line is not visible enough (I need thicker line):

[image]

I've set `$canvas->setStrokeAntialias(true);` but it doesn't help. If I increase the image resolution, then I need to make bigger stroke and in the end the result is the same. How can I achieve a nice antialiased line, which is also thick?

Here is my code:

```
$canvas = new \ImagickDraw();
$canvas->setStrokeColor($stroke_color);
$canvas->setFillColor($fill_color);
$canvas->setStrokeWidth($stroke_width);
$canvas->setStrokeAntialias(true);

$canvas->line(....);
$canvas->line(....);
$canvas->line(....);
...
```

---

**EDIT:** I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33890165/1181261) + reduced stroke of lines, but the result was the same.

Comment: Looks like your drawing each segment with `ImageDraw::line`, Try using `ImageDraw::polyline`.

Comment: Don't add setStrokeColor and setStrokeWidth. That just makes it wider. Just use setFillColor. Stroked outlines are antialiased by default, so remove setStrokeAntialias.

Comment: @emcconville, good point! Will try if this removes the jagged edges.

Comment: @fmw42 in that case, how do I control the thickness of the line?

Comment: If you really want thick lines, then you will need the setStrokeColor and setStrokeWidth. But try removing the setStrokeAntialias, since it is on by default. Polyline would be better as less work. What happens if you remove the shadow under and around the lines?

Comment: @fmw42, I was able to solve this using a polyline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on emcconville's comment, I was able to fix this by using polyline() to draw the line instead of many line() calls.

[image]